# Getting a value from the 2 dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this program I am supposed to create an 2 dimensional array such as `["S1","S2","S3","S4"]` AND `["John","Ben","Dan","Jim"]` and give the name as output when the specified serial no is given as input. Eg. John will be the output of S1.I was able to create the program using objects but I am unable to do it with arrays. I dont know how to create a 2 dimensional array as well. Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have an idea how to start?

Comment: There are no 2-dimensional arrays in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean nested arrays and the result you are after is:

```
[ [ 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4' ], [ 'John', 'Ben', 'Dan', 'Jim' ] ]
```

Consider the following:

```
var mainArray = [];

var arr1 = ["S1","S2","S3","S4"];
var arr2 = ["John","Ben","Dan","Jim"];

mainArray.push(arr1, arr2);
```

This should give you the result you are after. Please keep in mind that your question is a bit vague and doesn't tell us what you have tried. It sounds like you need some practice with basic JavaScript. I suggest finding tutorials online(which there are more than enough) and working through them.

For future reference, be sure to show what you have tried in your question.